# Campo (De: Nome) num e-mail em PHP

Tags: php

É o seguinte, o campo De (Nome) não aparece para quem recebe meu email, sabe aquele nome que passa o rato por cima e aparece o email do remetente, pois é, aparece direto o email do remetente.

Alguem sabe arrumar meu header?

**O código de enviar o html é:**

```
function sendmail() {
    if(!isset($_POST[Submit])) die("Não foi recebido nenhum parâmetro");
    /* Medida preventiva para evitar que outros domínios sejam remetente da sua mensagem. */
    if (eregi('tempsite.ws$|locaweb.com.br$|hospedagemdesites.ws$|websiteseguro.com$', $_SERVER[HTTP_HOST])) {
            $emailsender=trim($_POST['emailremetente']);
    } else {
            $emailsender = "noreply@" . $_SERVER[HTTP_HOST];
    }

    /* Verifica qual é o sistema operacional do servidor para ajustar o cabeçalho de forma correta. Não alterar */
    if(PHP_OS == "Linux") $quebra_linha = "\n";
    elseif(PHP_OS == "WINNT") $quebra_linha = "\r\n";
    else die("Incompatibilidade com Sistema Operacional");

    // Passando os dados obtidos pelo formulário para as variáveis abaixo
    $nomeremetente     = $_POST['nomeremetente'];
    $emailremetente    = trim($_POST['emailremetente']);
    $assunto           = $_POST['assunto'];

    $array_emaildestinatario = array();
    $array_emaildestinatario = explode("\n",trim($_POST['emaildestinatario'])); // separa os emails pelas vírgulas em uma array
    foreach($array_emaildestinatario as $elemento) {
        //pra cada email envia
        /* Montando a mensagem a ser enviada no corpo do e-mail. */
        $mensagemHTML = html();


        /* Montando o cabeçalho da mensagem */
        $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.1".$quebra_linha;
        $headers .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1".$quebra_linha;
        // Perceba que a linha acima contém "text/html", sem essa linha, a mensagem não chegará formatada.
        $headers .= "From: ".$emailsender.$quebra_linha;
        $headers .= "Return-Path: " . $emailsender . $quebra_linha;

        $headers .= "Reply-To: ".$emailremetente.$quebra_linha;
        // Note que o e-mail do remetente será usado no campo Reply-To (Responder Para)

        /* Enviando a mensagem */
        mail($elemento, $assunto, $mensagemHTML, $headers, "-r". $emailsender);
    }
    /* Mostrando na tela as informações enviadas por e-mail */
    ?>
        <div style="color:white;border:1px solid black;padding:15px;background-color:rgba(150,50,50,0.8);font-family:Arial;margin-bottom:5px;font-size:14px;">
            Enviando <?php echo count($array_emaildestinatario); ?> e-mails, aguarde um instante...
        </div>
        <div style="color:white;border:1px solid black;padding:15px;background-color:rgba(150,50,50,0.8);font-family:Arial;margin-bottom:5px;font-size:14px;">
            De:<?php echo $emailsender; ?>
        </div>
        <div style="color:white;border:1px solid black;padding-left:15px;padding-top:5px;padding-bottom:5px;background-color:rgba(150,50,50,0.3);font-family:Arial;margin-bottom:5px;font-size:14px;">
        <?php 
        foreach($array_emaildestinatario as $elemento) {
            echo "<p>$elemento</p>";
        }
        ?>
        </div>
<?php
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Tu deves usar o seguinte padrão para o cabeçalho `From:`

`Nome da Pessoa <noreply@example.com>`